samtools: command not found in bash script
So I wrote a bash code in which I am using samtools.
#!/bin/bash
# some
# code
samtools view -bS input.sam out.bam

while running this, I get the error :
samtools: command not found.

but I can run samtools fine in the terminal. I looked to the .bashrc file and looks like there is an alias for samtools: alias samtools='samtools_0.1.18' . I added this line at the begining of my code, after #!/bin/bash, but still I get the same error: samtools: command not found.
Any Idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance
cross posted here: https://www.biostars.org/p/9602827/#9602830

Generally speaking, instead of an alias you might want to setup a soft link in one of your PATH directories from samtools to samtools_0.1.18.

if the directory where samtools is installed is not on $PATH then it won't be found. at the terminal what does "type -a samtools" show, same as fore : "which samtools" also how is the bash script being run ? is it a cron job ?

so when I run: type -a samtools, I get samtools_0.1.18. But when I run which samtools I don't get anything. when I run which samtools_0.1.18 I get the path: /usr/bin/samtools_0.1.18

After sudo ln -s /usr/bin/samtools_0.1.18 /usr/bin/samtools you'd have a soft link, and wouldn't need to alias anymore.

Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm not a sudoer on that server.

Aliases are not expanded in scripts (unless the expand_aliases option is set using shopt).
Instead of an alias, define a function,
samtools () {
    samtools_0.1.18 "$@"
}
samtools view -bS input.sam out.bam

or use the full program name.
samtools_0.1.18 view -bS input.sam out.bam

If the path to the directory where samtools_0.1.18 is located is not in the $PATH variable, either add it there, or use the full path with the full name.
Creating a soft link is another option. This creates samtools in your bin directory (I assume you have ~/bin in your $PATH). Just make it point to a new version when you install one.
ln -s /usr/bin/samtools_0.1.18 ~/bin/samtools

